# PHP Array make up, the meaning of

Tags: php, arrays

I have  results of an MySQL query. If I then create an array like:

```
$List = array();    
do {
  $List[] = $row;
} while($row = $test->fetch_assoc());
```

When I echo the content I get:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [SeqID] => SeqID0201 ) [2] => Array ( [SeqID] => SeqID0202 ) [3] => Array ( [SeqID] => SeqID0203 ) )
```

If I then pass the array through a foreach loop

```
foreach($List as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

I get:

```
1 Array
2 Array
3 Array
```

My question, how can I get the content of the query result array to pass through the foreach loop to produce the data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a multidimensional array. `$value['SeqID']` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the result of :

```
foreach($List as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value['SeqID'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I don't know why I missed that. One last question, how can I get the result in to another array to use in a query, Like $fields[] = $key.' '.$value['SeqID'].'<br />';

Comment: Like that: $fields[$key] = $value['SeqID'];?

Comment: Hi, all I get is Array ( [] => ) when I print_r

Comment: With $fields[$key] = $value['SeqID'] in the foreach?

Comment: Hi, this is what I have: foreach($QList as $field => $val) {
    $fields[$key] = $value['SeqID'];
} and when I print_r I get Array ( [] => ). I have tried all manor of combinations with no joy

Comment: In the foreach you have: $QList as $field => $val, so it will be: $fields[$field] = $val['SeqID']; Do you understand?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I now have: $fields = array();
foreach($List as $fields => $value) {
    $fields[$key] = $value['SeqID'];
} and when I rin the script I get: Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: Yes, you should have foreach($List as $key => $value)

Comment: And $List must be an array

Comment: Hi, Many thnaks for all your time. Perfect. Thank you again